# Scripting: [ ! -d dir ] meaning

Tags: linux, linux-mint, linux-kernel

```
if [ ! -d /home/dir ]; then

   mkdir /home/dir

fi
```

A friend of mines and I came across this one day in class, we both had different answers to it, but I kind of want to prove to him that I may be right.

he says it 
"creates the directory /home/dir only if it does not exist"

I said no that it
"deletes the directory /home/dir and then makes it again"

Who is right?...or are we both wrong?

Comment: He is right... `-d <FILE>`: True, if <FILE> exists and is a directory.

Comment: Aww crap, now I owe him lunch lol.  I was pretty sure I had it right, thanks for your help buddy.  Also thanks for the edit, I'm new to this website.  How did you make the syntax look like that when asking a question?

Comment: You can use the visual tools above the text box to format your question, or just use markdown directly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script & https://superuser.com/questions/98825/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-linux-command-line

Answer (score 4):

Your friend is nearly right, the script creates `/home/dir` only if it is not already a directory. (If it’s something else, `mkdir` will be run but will fail.)

`[` introduces a test, which here is `! -d /home/dir`; `-d /home/dir` checks whether `/home/dir` exists and is a directory, and `!` negates that. All this wrapped in `if` / `then` means that if `/home/dir` is not already a directory, `mkdir /home/dir` is run.

With `mkdir` specifically, a more concise way of writing all that is

```
mkdir -p /home/dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is right. It's like "if not is a directory"

But tell him you can leave the whole condition and just write `mkdir -p /home/dir`

Comment: Oh wow, that sounds a lot simpler, THANKS!!...we are new to Linux, scripting is pretty tough I must say.

Comment: Of course, so many commands with so many options. Playing around and reading man pages will help you. Have fun.